# Refer to an array using a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, reference

I am writing a page that collects serial numbers for parts installed in an assembly.  I want to validate the user input on the client-side, if I can.

So if I have multiple dense arrarys, how can I refer to them using a varaiable? For instance, say I have three densely packed arrays who's names represent part numbers, and who's values represent serial numbers (that have been consumed in other assemblies).

```
arr_PN-123-ABC = ('SN0123','SN0124','SN0125')
arr_PN-456-DEF = ('SN00333','SN00334','SN00335')
arr_PN-789-GHI = ('SN-0001','SN-0002','SN-0003','SN-0004')

function fcnValidateSN(_givenPN, _givenSN) {

  //make sure the given values are not null or empty...

  //derive the array of serial numbers that coorsponds to the given part number...
  var vArrName = "arr_" + vGivenPN;

  //loop thru the array of serial numbers to determine if the given sn was already used...
  for(var x=0; x < vArrName.length(); x++) {
    if(vArrName[x]==_givenSN) {
      alert("Serial number '" + _givenSN + "' was already used in another assembly.");
      theForm.txtPN.focus();
      return;
    }


  } //end 'for' loop

} //end fcnValidateSN()
```

So the problem is that 'vArrName' is a string with a value of 'arr_' instead of a refernece to an array who's name is 'arr_'.

I tried wrapping it with the eval() function, but eval() treats dashes as minus signs.

One other note: I cannot use jquery for this effort.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- An array in JavaScript is delimitated by `[` and `]`, not `(` or `)`.
- A valid JavaScript variable name can't contain '-'
- The length property of an array isn't a function

Well, I've done some (actually, a lot of) adjustments in your code, but I think this is what you need:

```
var serialGroups = {
  PN_123_ABC: ['SN0123','SN0124','SN0125'],
  PN_456_DEF: ['SN00333','SN00334','SN00335'],
  PN_789_GHI: ['SN-0001','SN-0002','SN-0003','SN-0004']
};

function validateSerial(groupName, sn) {
  var serials = serialGroups[groupName];

  for(var i=0; i < serials.length; i++){
    if(serials[i] == sn) {
      alert("Serial number '" + sn + "' was already used in another assembly.");
      //Do whatever you want here
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: alcides - thank you, I was able to use your method to get my function working. One thing though: a javascript DENSE array IS delimited using '(' & ')', but it is moot in this case since I am no longer using them. Since the population of part numbers I am using contain '-' characters, I had to replace them with '_' when naming an individual group - since this case is predictable, it works just fine. (my 'reputation' isn't high enough to 'up-vote' on your answer - this is the first time I have asked a question on stack)

Comment: Well, the only thing the statement `var a = (111,222,333)` does is to treat the comma separated list as an expression, by using the parentheses syntax, and, since the values are separated by the comma operator, the last is returned as the value of the whole expression, then assigned to the variable a. There's nothing like Dense Array Syntax in EcmaScript nor Standard JavaScript. If you're using some other flavor, please tell us, but this is not standard.

Comment: Netscape One Developer's Guide, William R. Stanek (@1997) - Page 43 (Densley Populated Arrays) Sample From Book: Continents= new Array("Africa","Asia","Austraila","Antarctica","Europe","North America","South America") This syntax works just fine - I cannot comment on what the 'standards' have to say about it, I googled 'javascript dense array' and had lots of hits including this one: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/densearray2.shtml.  Regardless, the dense array was not what solved this issue, it was your code - so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate a reference to a variable declared with `var` (except see below). You can use dynamic property names to refer to properties of objects, so:

```
var arrays = {
  "arr_PN-123-ABC": ['SN0123','SN0124','SN0125'],
  "arr_PN-456-DEF": ['SN00333','SN00334','SN00335'],
  // ...
};
```

Then:

```
console.log( arrays["arr_PN-" + num + "ABC"][0] ); // SN0123
```

Note that you cannot use "-" in a variable name, but you *can* use it in an object property name.

The exception to not being able to access `var` variables by dynamic name is made for global variables in a browser. Those variables all end up as properties of the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single object that has the arrays as elements:

```
var arr_PN = {
    '123-ABC': ('SN0123','SN0124','SN0125'),
    '456-DEF': ('SN00333','SN00334','SN00335'),
    '789-GHI': ('SN-0001','SN-0002','SN-0003','SN-0004')
}
```

And then reference using:

```
var vArrName = arr_PN->{vGivenPN};
```

Comment: This contains syntax errors; that's not what JavaScript array literals look like, and I don't know what that code in the last line is supposed to be.